# Slack: How to track when team members log out?

Tags: slack-api

I'm using Slack's [Real Time Messaging API](https://api.slack.com/rtm) to track when my team members log into or out of Slack. Using the [presence_change](https://api.slack.com/events/presence_change) and [manual_presence_change](https://api.slack.com/events/manual_presence_change) events I am notified when someone explicit changes their presence state (or if they're automatically set to "Away" after a period of inactivity).

But if a team members logs out (e.g. closes the Slack app) I do not receive any type of notification. Am I missing something or is there no way to be notified when someone logs into or out of Slack? I really don't want to have to resort to polling.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This looks like a very demanding application from a user point of view

Comment: Probably you don't receive the notification because the user is still active somehow. Maybe slack don't change the user presence when the app is closed and only after the automatic period.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46711079/4379151) might be helpful.